# friendCount not printing expected output

Tags: python, string, selenium, integer, driver

I'm trying to make a web scraper that prints all of the names of my facebook friends, but I'm getting an unexpected output.

The relevant code is:

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/redacted/friends")

friendCount = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3d0")
print(friendCount)
```

but it's printing

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7b784934706f2f102a4918fbe734726d", element="695f03b8-d6a5-4879-8575-01d52b720f79")>
```

I attempted to force the string into an integer by using:

```
friendCount = int(driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3d0"))
```

but that prints out

```
    friendCount = int(driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3d0"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'WebElement'
```

is there anything I can do to turn this into an integer?

Comment: this is `WebElement` object. If what you are looking for is really under this one element, then I guess you wanted to properly print here. So, better use `print(friendCount.text)` or make int from it if you like: `int(friendCount.text)`

Answer (score 0):

As Krzysztof mentioned, adding .text to the variable prints out the number. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're code is searching for a single web element (and printed it out). If you are looking for a list of friends, and not just one, you should use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` instead of `driver.find_element_by_class_name`

and yes it should be `.text` to return name and not the web element itself.

```
friendCount = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_3d0")
for x in friendCount:
    print(x.text)
```

Or if you want just the count of friends.

```
friendCount = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_3d0")
print(len(friendCount))
```